# Let $L$ a linear operator. Show that if $L$ is injective, then $\det(L)\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Let $L$ a linear operator. Show that if $L$ is injective, then $\det(L)\neq 0$.

How would I prove this?

My current progress :
If $L$ is injective, it has leading $1$ in every column of it's RREF. This implies that it is linearly independent. The columns of an invertible matrix are also linearly independent, therefore $L$ is invertible. Since, $L$ is invertible, it's determinant cannot equal $0$.

This doesn't seem right though. Is there a better proof for this?

Answer (score 1):

Because $L$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$ (with $V$ a vector space), $L$ being injective is equivalent to it being bijection (why?). In other words, if it is injective, it is invertible (with a linear inverse), which is equivalent to the determinant not being zero.